# spring annotation bases configuration

Tags: java, spring

How to write a fully annotation based configuration

```
@Component
public class MessageServiceHelper {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("emailService")
    private MessageService messageService;

    public MessageService getMessageService() {
        return messageService;
    }

    public void setMessageService(MessageService messageService) {
        this.messageService = messageService;
    }

    public boolean sendMessage(String message){
        return this.messageService.sendMessage(message);
    }


@Component
@Qualifier("emailService")
public class EmailServiceImpl implements MessageService {

    @Override
    public boolean sendMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println("EmailServiceImpl.sendMessage " + message);
        return true;
    }
}


@Component
public interface MessageService {
    boolean sendMessage(String message);
}

@Component
public class SmsServiceImpl implements MessageService {
    @Override
    public boolean sendMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println("SmsServiceImpl.sendMessage " + message);
        return true;
    }
}

public class Application {
    @Autowired
    MessageServiceHelper messageServiceHelper;

    @Autowired
    public Application application;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //How can I get messageservicehelper here and call the method.

    }
}
```

so basically the thing is I dont want any xml file in my configuration, how can I do that.?

## update

I don't want to use javabased configuration is it possible to configure spring without configuring anything in xml?

Comment: You are already using java based configuration, as you have a `@Configuration` class...

Comment: So you don't want to use annotations or xml for configuration?

Comment: @M.Deinum I have removed @ Configuration

Comment: Without configuring anything??? ;p May be u can try Springboot(http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/), it supports @EnableAutoConfiguration, only very minimal configuration is needed

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use spring 3.X annotation without any .xml configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059171/how-to-use-spring-3-x-annotation-without-any-xml-configuration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all clean up your code putting annotations on an interface isn't going to work. Next `@Configuration` is a `@Component` so what is this class configuration or a component don't try to do both. Generally a bad idea.

You are using field level annotations so your getters and setters don't add anything, only code that isn't used. I would also suggest to use constructor injection instead of setters or field injection. (For a read on why field injection is evil read [this post](http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/)).

All this applied would lead to the following code.

The `MessageServiceHelper` with a constructor instead of setters or field injection.

```
@Component
public class MessageServiceHelper {
    private final MessageService messageService;

    @Autowired
    public MessageServiceHelper(@Qualifier("emailService") MessageService messageService) {
        this.messageService=messageService;
    }

    public boolean sendMessage(String message){
        return this.messageService.sendMessage(message);
    }
}
```

The `MessageService` and its implementations.

```
public interface MessageService {
    boolean sendMessage(String message);
}
```

The `EmailServiceImpl`.

```
@Component
@Qualifier("emailService")
public class EmailServiceImpl implements MessageService {

    @Override
    public boolean sendMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println("EmailServiceImpl.sendMessage " + message);
        return true;
    }
}
```

The `SmsServiceImpl`.

```
@Component
public class SmsServiceImpl implements MessageService {
    @Override
    public boolean sendMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println("SmsServiceImpl.sendMessage " + message);
        return true;
    }
}
```

The `@Configuration`.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "demo.di")
public class ApplicationConfiguration {}
```

And the starter for the application.

```
public class Application

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationConfiguration.class);
        MessageHelper helper = ctx.getBean(MessageHelper.class);
        helper.sendMessage("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use the `@Configuration` (which eventually you will when you want to use things like transactions, AOP etc.) use the constructor which takes a `String...` and pass `demo.di` instead of class. This will scan, starting from that package, all `@Component`s.

```
public class Application

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("demo.di");
        MessageHelper helper = ctx.getBean(MessageHelper.class);
        helper.sendMessage("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are 4 ways you can configure spring context:

1. XML config
2. Annotation-based config
3. Java-based config
4. Groovy config file

In each of this configurations you must tell spring where to find spring beans definitions.

In the case with Java-based config you can try something like this to bootstrap spring context:

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context =
    new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext (Application.class);
MessageServiceHelper helper= context.getBean(MessageServiceHelper.class);
```

Refer to [Spring Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java) for more info

Comment: That is old, very old and not maintained any more. That was the spring java config project, which is now (largely) merged into the core of Spring.

Comment: @M.Deinum True. Edited my answer